# Acumatica: when the data changed, message "leave site?" "Changes you made may not be saved" doesn't appear to prevent loosing the changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Usually in all Acumatica pages, when you make a change, the framework throws you standard javascript message: "Changes you made may not be saved" to prevent you from loosing changes:

[image]

or

[image]

What setting causing this behavior?
I have a screen where there is no such dialog and I don't know how to cause it happens.

This problematic page is a pop up window:
[image]

this popup opened when you use This issue doesn't happen when you open the popup with `PXRedirectRequiredException`:

```
throw new PXPopupRedirectException(currentPayCalendarMaint, true, string.Empty);
```

When you open it with `PXRedirectRequiredException`:

```
throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(currentPayCalendarMaint, true, string.Empty);
```

the framework opens dialog as regular browser popup and shows required message ("Changes you made may not be saved") as expected:

[image]

Is that possible to have the requried behavior without opening the popup as a separate window?

I will be grateful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the only way to resolve the problem is to open in new standard browser window like this:
[image]
Instead of Aucmatica dialog:
[image]

To achieve this, we need to open the dialog with:

```
throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(currentPayCalendarMaint, true, string.Empty)
            {
                Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
            };
```

Instead of this:

```
throw new PXPopupRedirectException(currentPayCalendarMaint, string.Empty, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in normal cases, this is tied directly to the IsDirty flag on the graph or a cache in the graph.  When a value in any cache is changed, the graph's IsDirty flag is set to true.  I have seen some code that manually sets IsDirty to false on specific caches to cause what you are describing as your issue.  It is possible this has occurred, but it also is possible that your code does not actually update any values in any of the caches.  Without your code, I can only speculate.

Comments from the source code where IsDirty is defined in PX.Data.PXGraph:

```
// Summary:
//     Gets the value that indicates whether there are modified data records not saved
//     to the database in the caches related to the graph data views. If the IsDirty
//     property of at least one cache object is true, the IsDirty property of the graph
//     is also true.
public virtual bool IsDirty { get; }
```

Excerpts from SOCreateShipment using a constructor for Orders:

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXFilteredProcessing<SOOrder, SOOrderFilter> Orders;
...

public virtual IEnumerable orders()
{
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<SOOrder.customerID>(Caches[typeof(SOOrder)], Messages.CustomerID);
    ...
    PXView.StartRow = 0;

    Orders.Cache.IsDirty = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge. In my case one graph opens another graph and the problem is in PXPopupRedirectException. This issue doesn't happen when you open the popup with PXRedirectRequiredException.

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail.  Looks like something Hughes (aka HB_Acumatica) will know, but this is beyond me.

Comment: I verified: in my case the cache IsDirty is true, so the it looks like a limitation of PXPopupRedirectException. It doesn't require to save, because probably this new dialog considered as it is in the same context. So the only way is to open in new dialog until Acumatica will resolve this issue.